# Displaying alert box on button - Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Good Day

I am using a form that uses knocknout to add data.
Now when one clicks on the 'remove' button(see below), it removes the entry without warning. How do I alert the user first that he is about to remove the item?

Thank you

HTML

```
   <td><input type="button" class="register" value="Remove" data-bind="click: function(){ vm.Remove($data) }" /></td>
```

Knockout

```
 var vm = {
            Data: ko.observable(),

            Remove: function (card)
            {
                console.log(card.CardId());

                var d = {
                    cardId: card.CardId()
                }

                var options =
                {
                    url: "MyAccount.aspx/DeleteCard",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(d),

                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        window.location = window.location;
                    }
                }

                $.ajax(options);
            }
        }

        var cardsBound = false;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            LoadCards();
            $("#")
        });

        function LoadCards() {
            var options =
            {
                url: "MyAccount.aspx/GetCardTypes",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",

                success: function (response) {

                    vm.Data(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)));

                    if (!cardsBound)
                        ko.applyBindings(vm);
                    cardsBound = true;
                }
            }
            $.ajax(options);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) to open up a confirmation-box, catch the response  and only delete if the response is `true`. Something like this:

```
data-bind="click: function(){ if (confirm('Delete, really?')) { vm.Remove($data) } }"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special to knockout.js about it, just use the JavaScript function `confirm()`:

```
data-bind="click: function(){ if (confirm('really?') vm.Remove($data) }"
```